# Subview animation stops working when parent view is resized

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I have a UIView mainView which has 2 rows of cells inside it. Each cell is a UIView that was added to the mainView using:

```
[mainView addSubiew:cell];
```

When a cell on the row 2 is tapped, I move all row 2 cells to row 1:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

//change frame.origin.y of each row 2 cell to that of the cell right above it

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The above works perfectly fine. However, after this, I am trying to resize mainView:

```
CGRect newFrame = mainView.frame;
newFrame.size.height -= cellHeight;  //cellHeight is the size of a cell
mainView.frame = newFrame
```

Now, neither the animation above works, nor the resizing of mainView works.

I commented out all the animation code above and found that the resizing of the mainView by itself does not work either.

mainView was set up as follows:

```
mainView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
mainView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Not sure what's going on :(